# Please advise if this posting is off-topic

Tags: discussion

I posted this *[question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1157805/measure-of-non-measurable-set-is-zero)* yesterday, received great feedback and was able to solve my problem. Many, many thanks to @Tom and @Henning Makholm.

But today I see that the posting was voted twice for closure because it is "off topic." Can anyone advise me why it is considered as "off topic," please? I would like to be a good citizen of this MSE-land :-).

Thank you very much.

Comment: BTW your post already wen through review queue, three people voted to leave open. So it is not very probable that the question is going to be closed. When I click on close and the on off-topic, I can see that the two users who voted chose this reason for closure: *This question is missing context or other details: Please [improve the question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959) by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it....*

Comment: *This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.* I do not know whether you can also see this information somewhere. But if the post were closed (i.e., if there would be five votes to close), the same text would be shown below the question. So you would be given at least this information why the users chose to vote this way. (And some of them might even leave a comment.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak : Thank you sir! I am just very curious to find out how heavyweights are perceiving my posting, to improve response rate. :-)  Thanks again!

Comment: The issue has been explained to you explicitly: You are asking a question about a specific set $N$ without describing what $N$ is. That is what "missing context" indicates. Add the definition of $N$. Also, be more detailed about the book this comes from: Title, edition, page, etc.

Comment: Thanks! I can understand the issue around the title of the book, but as far as definition of $N$ is concerned, I have immediately responded to Henning Makholm's request by giving him with a link, it should have been resolved by then. But anyway, thanks again for your input though.

Comment: @A.Magnus I tried to answer the question: *How can I find what reasons chose the people who voted to close?* (Which is a general question - it can be asked about every question which received a close vote.) If you are particularly interesting in getting some feedback on this particular question, you should add ([meta-tag:specific-question]) tag to your post on meta.

Comment: @A.Magnus Not for nothing, but your question really should be as self-contained as possible. In part, an "expert" in the area shouldn't need to look up external sources to determine what your question is about (in this case, the set $N$). (And while responding to requests for clarifications in comments pings those users, it is _much_ preferred to edit your question to include important information.)

Comment: @ArthurFischer : Got it! Will make sure next time posting is self-contained! Thanks also for Martin for pointing out "specific question." Thanks again to both of you for taking your time!